# Difference Between Monitor & Lock?

Tags: locking, thread-synchronization, mutual-exclusion

What's the difference between a [monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) and a [lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29)?

If a lock is simply an implementation of mutual exclusion, then is a monitor simply a way of making use of the waiting time inbetween method executions?

A good explanation would be really helpful thanks....

regards

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For example in C# .NET a lock statement is equivalent to:

```
Monitor.Enter(object);
try
{
    // Your code here...
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(object);
}
```

However, keep in mind that Monitor can also `Wait()` and `Pulse()`, which are often useful in complex multithreading situations.

**Edit:**
In later versions of the .NET framework, this was changed to:

```
bool lockTaken = false;
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(object, ref lockTaken);
    // Your code here...
}
finally
{
    if (lockTaken)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not provide the verbal form of the relation between notions "lock" and "monitor".

Answer (score 4):

They're related. For example, in C# the [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) statement is a simple try-finally wrapper around [entering a Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx) and [exiting one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.exit.aspx) when done.

Comment: Can you describe the relation between them in your own words?

Answer (score 1):

Monitors are compiler-assisted "semi-automatic" locks. They allow one to declare `synchronized` methods on classes, etc. This is just a different approach to providing mutual exclusion. I found [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633388) to be the most thorough explanation of the concepts, even though it's mostly geared towards OS developers.

Answer (score 0):

A lock ensures mutual exclusion.

A monitor associates the data to be protected and the mutual exclusion and synchronization primitives required to protect accesses to the data.
Synchronization is used e.g. when you need one thread to wait until an event occurs (e.g., wait until another thread places an item in a queue).

Answer (score 0):

Monitors is a programming-language construct that does the same thing as semiphores/locks, but Monitors control the shared data by synchronizing at run time. In contrast, locks protect the shared data by just "spinning" which can lead to poor CPU utilization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, lock generates Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit within a try/finally block. Using Monitor over lock allows you to fine tune because it has Pulse and PulseAll. You can also have alternate processing should you be unable to acquire the lock with TryEnter.

Answer (score 0):

Monitor is the concept and Lock is the actual implementation.

Comment: Why is this answer negatively scored? Can the scorer provide explanation in the comment? Because from whatever I have seen so far, nobody really know the exact relation between the notion of "lock" and the notion of "monitor". Everyone seems to avoid this relationship by defining each separately, which does not answer the question. This is the only specific answer I have found so far: notion: "lock" relation: "is the actual implementation of" notion: "monitor". Nobody that I have read has ever provided the relation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have researched so far, monitor is a set of principles for thread synchronization, while locks are, along with "thread cooperation" facilities like wait and notify, the way monitors are implemented in Java. So effectively, if we try to form the exact relationship between the two notions, locks are one part of the implementation of monitors (the other being wait and notify mechanisms). Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I would really appreciate if the correction is very specific.

Answer (score -1):

Lock focus on only mutual exculsion, but
Moniter provides mutual exclusion automatically.

So we don't need to worry of using mutual exclusion in Monitor.
Instead of ME, we need to consern of sycronzing only when we do programming.

Moniter provides more systematical way of programming.
It, therefor, is more advanced one.